# IIS URL Rewrite Module: "Infinite" Pairs of variables?

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

What single pattern would support all of these url forms (and their rewritten forms)?

http://www.domain.com/varAName/varAValue
http://www.domain.com/?varAName=varAValue

http://www.domain.com/varAName/varAValue/varBName/varBValue
http://www.domain.com/?varAName=varAValue&varBName=varBValue

http://www.domain.com/varAName/varAValue/varBName/varBValue/varCName/varCValue
http://www.domain.com/?varAName=varAValue&varBName=varBValue&varCName=varCValue

The wizard for User-Friendly URLs is nice, but the RegEx it writes makes every position of the pattern required.  I need one that essentially would support MANY key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible with IIS URL Rewrite 2, since it doesn't support many matchings for inbound URLs.

You would need to create N rules to match each "length" - Be sure of creating the rules in a web.config and not in ApplicationHost.config (Server Rule), because it will use a rewrite cache for very efficient rewriting.

Second option is to create a custom provider in C#/.NET; but that [requires coding](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/rewriteextensibility).